# Where can I get all the cli commands for the cleos wallet from block.one?

Tags: cleos

Where can one find all the cleos commands for the cli wallet?

Comment: `$ cleos wallet` will list them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [developers.eos.io](https://developers.eos.io) which seems to be up-to-date.
There, [cleos command reference](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference) is currently accessible from the upper menu.